# Are there methods to represent entire knowledge graphs using a single embedding vector?

Tags: embeddings, knowledge-graph

In a knowledge graph, embedding vectors can be learned for nodes (node embedding) and edges (edge embeddings). Is there a method to learn one single embedding vector for the entire knowledge graph?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is Graph Readout operation can get a graph level representation out of the node/edge representations. Read the following:
https://lifesci.dgl.ai/api/model.readout.html